# Exception with proxy or filter in k8s

Tags: exception, kubernetes, domain-driven-design, microservices

I have domain based microservices architecture but want to handle exception handling in more generic way...I want a wrapper kind of service in generic way so that I can utilise this to send meaningful messages to upstream systems... I heard of proxy and filters but can somebody guide on how to implement or any other way ... Reason of implementing separately is, I don't want to modify each end point call on code

Comment: You need to be more specific?

Comment: I have 30 different micro services which talk to each other and there might be exceptions right...let's say some http internal errors occurred, then i want to capture them using proxy or filters... which should be generic across and should monitor all errors and patterns occuring

Comment: Im not sure but I think you are misinterpreting handling exceptions and monitoring the exceptions. You should handle the exceptions within your apps that's the best way, for example when you get 503 request will be send again or resend to a different address to handle something like load balancer on L7.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have to handle while monitoring...is there a way ... exception are handled within services but I want to overwrite the messages set with some meaningful description added to them during that process...so if I can do it on wrapper kindoflayer I don't have to touch all 30 odd services and change descriptions for any kind of exceptions

Comment: Are you on a cloud env or on-prem?

Comment: We are On prem and k8s

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Nginx Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) and use [custom-http-errors](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#custom-http-errors).

> Enables which HTTP codes should be passed for processing with the  [error_page directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)
>
> Setting at least one code also enables  [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors)  which are required to process error_page.
>
> Example usage:  `custom-http-errors: 404,415`

This would work with creating a ConfigMap to ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
name: nginx-configuration-ext
data:
  custom-http-errors: 502,503,504
  proxy-next-upstream-tries: "2"
  server-tokens: "false"
```

Also have a look at this [blog post](https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/445596/).

Another way would be adding `Annotations` to your ingress, it will catch the errors you want and redirect it to different service in this case `nginx-errors-svc`

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: nginx-errors-svc
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: 404,503
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: error-pages
```

If you will have issues using that try using [server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) which will add custom configuration in the server configuration block :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location @custom_503 {
        return 404;
      }
      error_page 503 @custom_503;
```

You should consider reading [Custom Error Handling with the Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller](https://tech.holidayextras.com/custom-error-handling-with-the-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-f7861b08ffd7) and [Custom Error Page for Nginx Ingress Controller](https://itnext.io/custom-error-page-for-nginx-ingress-controller-cca4cfa82bb9).

Comment: Will get back..thats loads of information..thanks pal